# How to convert format date from PHP to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php file which I will later change into the form of an HTML file, which be current constraints are:
**- Date format using Javascript.**

Her script like the following snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <?php
        /* Set start and end dates here */
        $startDate  = strtotime("15 August 2012 12:00:00");
        $endDate    = strtotime("15 November 2012 12:00:00");
        /* /Set start and end dates here */
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            JBCountDown({
                secondsColor : "#ffdc50",
                minutesColor : "#9cdb7d",
                hoursColor   : "#378cff",
                daysColor    : "#ff6565",

                startDate   : "<?php echo $startDate; ?>",
                endDate     : "<?php echo $endDate; ?>",
                now         : "<?php echo strtotime('now'); ?>",
                seconds     : "<?php echo date("s"); ?>"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

please help me to overcome it.
I want to run a php script in javascript that is being subordinated.

example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            JBCountDown({
                secondsColor : "#ffdc50",
                minutesColor : "#9cdb7d",
                hoursColor   : "#378cff",
                daysColor    : "#ff6565",

                startDate   : startDate,  //format time in JS
                endDate     : endDate,  //format time in JS
                now         : strtotime('now'),  //format time in JS
                seconds     : date("s")
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Please help, 
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can all be done in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

        //http://www.convert-unix-time.com/

        var unix = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);  //unix timestamp for todays date
        //alert(unix);

            JBCountDown({
                secondsColor : "#ffdc50",
                secondsGlow  : "none",

                minutesColor : "#9cdb7d",
                minutesGlow  : "none",

                hoursColor   : "#378cff",
                hoursGlow    : "none",

                daysColor    : "#ff6565",
                daysGlow     : "none",

                startDate   : "1362096000 ", //unix timestamp for ' Friday 1st March 2013 12:00:00 AM'
                endDate     : "1373328000", //unix timestamp for 'Tuesday 9th July 2013 01:00:00 AM'
                now         : unix,
                seconds     : unix % 60 //unix timestamp for seconds in realtime
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime() and date():

```
$originalDate = "2010-03-21";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

(see [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) and [date](http://php.net/date) docs on the PHP site).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        /* Set start and end dates here */
$startDate  = new DateTime("15 August 2012 12:00:00");
$endDate    = new DateTime("15 November 2012 12:00:00");
/* /Set start and end dates here */

print $startDate->format('FORMAT');
?>
```

See all date time formats: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Comment: thank you so much for providing input, but my intent was to change the date format in php into javascript.